# How to get value of selected page template in Gutenberg editor?

Tags: javascript, editor, block-editor, post-editor

How to detect the value of selected page template in the edit page? I have used jQuery to select the page attribute select box but it is not working when we hide the editor sidebar; Because it removes the markup of that settings. I think it keeps data somewhere as we are able to bring back the sidebar without any change.

My code:
`$('.editor-page-attributes__template select').val()`

Is there any way to get the value when the sidebar is closed? Like any JavaScript variable in the page that updates when we change page template.

Note: I mean getting the value and use it in JavaScript without refreshing or updating the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I slightly modified SkyShab's code, because it fired template change event on page load and it didn't fire when template was changed to default (since getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' ) is then '', which equals to null when testing for template change)

```
const { select, subscribe } = wp.data;

class PageTemplateSwitcher {

    constructor() {
        this.template = null;
    }

    init() {

        subscribe( () => {

            const newTemplate = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' );
            if (newTemplate !== undefined && this.template === null) {
                this.template = newTemplate;
            }

            if ( newTemplate !== undefined && newTemplate !== this.template ) {
                this.template = newTemplate;
                this.changeTemplate();
            }

        });
    }

    changeTemplate() {
        // do your stuff here
        console.log('template changed to ${this.template}');
    }
}

new PageTemplateSwitcher().init();
```

Answer (score 3):

To get this value, use the wp.data module.

```
const template = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' );
```

Since this can be changed in the document settings, you would likely need to "subscribe" and run a callback whenever this changes.

For example:

```
const { select, subscribe } = wp.data;

class PageTemplateSwitcher {

  constructor() {
    this.template = null;
  }

  init() {

    subscribe( () => {

      const newTemplate = select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'template' );

      if ( newTemplate && newTemplate !== this.template ) {
        this.template = newTemplate;
        this.changeTemplate();
      }

    });
  }

  changeTemplate() {
    // do your stuff here
    console.log(`template changed to ${this.template}`);
  }
}

new PageTemplateSwitcher().init();
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to learn more about `wp.data`, here's the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/